# Transfering elements to a new list

Tags: python

I have to print out all the elements of this list that are less than 5:

```
a = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
a = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
b = []
for i in range (len(a)-1):
    i+=1
    if a.index(i) < 5:
        print(i)
        b.append(i)
print(b)
```

However, after running the program I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/list10.py", line 5, in <module>
    if a.index(i) < 5:
ValueError: 4 is not in list
```

Comment: The `a.index(i)` function gives you the index of the first item with value `i` in the list `a`. It doesn't give you the value of the i'th item in the list. For that, use: `a[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

you can get what you want using:

```py
print([x for x in a if x < 5])
```

more about list comprehensions in python:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

I think list comprehension as proposed by Georgy Kopshteyn and Ammar is the best solution, but as you are a beginner, here is a simpler way that may be easier to understand – the result is exactly the same:

```py
a = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
b = []

for x in a:
    if x < 5:
        b.append(x)
```

`b` now contains all the elements you need, you can print them or process them in any other way. If all you want is to print the values, you don't need `b` at all, just

```py
for x in a:
    if x < 5:
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are exactly what you are looking for, but I can point out why your code didn't work

```
a = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
b = []
for i in range(len(a)-1): # You should loop up to len(a) if you want to reach all the elements in a
    i+=1 # No need to increment i because the for loop increments i automatically
    if a.index(i) < 5: # I think you meant to use a[i]. a.index(i) searches for the position of i in a
        print(i) # you printed the index, however, you want to print the element of a at the index (i.e. a[i])
        b.append(i) # same idea, use a[i] instead of i
print(b)
```

Instead you could do:

```
a = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
b = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] < 5:
        print(a[i])
        b.append(a[i])
print(b)
```

But if you wanted to be more concise:

```
a = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
b = []
for i in a: # In this version, i is not the index. Instead, i is an element of a 
    if i < 5:
        print(i)
        b.append(i)
print(b)
```

Or you could use list comprehension:

```
def print_and_return(x):
    print(x)
    return x

b = [print_and_return(i) for i in a if i < 5]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Via list comprehension:

```
b = [x for x in a if x < 5]
print(b)
```

Via `filter()`:

```
b = list(filter(lambda x: x < 5, a))
print(b)
```

Comment: It's the same answer made by @Ammar isn't it?

Comment: @Carmoreno It essentially is, but I posted mine (seconds) before him.

Comment: @SilvioStoykov You're welcome! I have also added an alternative way to do it using the `filter()` function to my post.